# Java JsonPath: Extract nested json object as string

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I need to get a json string, that is part of a larger json.
As a simplified example, I want to extract only file01, and I need the json object as a string.

```
{
    "file01": {
        "id": "0001"
    },
    "file02": {
        "id": "0002"
    }
}
```

So, in code something like:

```
String file01 = JsonPath.parse(jsonFile).read("$.file01").toJson();
System.out.println(file01);  // {"id":"0001"}
```

I would like to use the library [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath), but I do not know how to get what I need.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: which library is this `JsonPath` ?

Comment: Jayway JsonPath  from https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default parser in `JsonPath` will read everything as a `LinkedHashMap` so the output of `read()` will be a `Map`. You *could* use a library such as Jackson or Gson to serialise this `Map` into a JSON string. However, you can also get `JsonPath` to do this for you internally.

To do this within `JsonPath` you configure `JsonPath` with a different implementation of `AbstractJsonProvider`, one which allows you to get your hands on the parsed result as JSON. In the following example, we're using `GsonJsonProvider` and the output of the `read()` method *is* a JSON string.

```
@Test
public void canParseToJson() {
    String json = "{\n" +
            "    \"file01\": {\n" +
            "        \"id\": \"0001\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"file02\": {\n" +
            "        \"id\": \"0002\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}";

    Configuration conf = Configuration.builder().jsonProvider(new GsonJsonProvider()).build();

    JsonObject file01 = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(json).read("$.file01");

    // prints out {"id":"0001"}
    System.out.println(file01);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that works!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("yourjson.json"));

Object res = JsonPath.read(obj, "$"); //your json path extract expression by denoting $

System.out.println(res);}
```